# How do I expose form elements as an API?

Tags: forms

I have tried `drupal_get_form($form_id)` to get the form elements, but it didn't help me.

Is there a way to get all the form fields (type, label etc.,) so I can write a service to expose it as an API?

Comment: The return from `drupal_get_form` is an array containing all form elements. There's no other way to get that data array. What are you finding is missing from that array that you need for your API?

Comment: Also, are you trying to get the form elements as HTML output?

Comment: @Clive drupal_get_form is not returning all the form elements. I tried to get the article form drupal_get_form('article_node_form'); but i didn't get all the elements especially title, body fields were missing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno i want form elements as an array.

Comment: They're probably just not in the top level of the array, they're definitely there or the form wouldn't ever work (core uses exactly that method itself). Use element_children to recursively loop through the array children

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to get the node edit form (i.e. an entity edit form), you need to pass to `drupal_get_form()` also the node object to be edited, in the same way [`node_page_edit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.pages.inc/function/node_page_edit/7.x) does.

```
function node_page_edit($node) {
  $type_name = node_type_get_name($node);
  drupal_set_title(t('<em>Edit @type</em> @title', array('@type' => $type_name, '@title' => $node->title)), PASS_THROUGH);
  return drupal_get_form($node->type . '_node_form', $node);
}
```

Passing `NULL` as node object has the effect that some Drupal functions will *silenty* fail. For example, imagine the effect of the following lines when `$node` has been set to `NULL`.

```
  if (!isset($node->$key)) {
    $node->$key = (int) in_array($key, $node_options);
  }
```

The other effects of passing NULL to what Drupal expects to be a node object is that Drupal is not able to find which entity fields are attached to the content type of the node (which includes the body field), and it is not able to understand if the content type is set to show a title. The effect is Drupal not showing any form field to edit the title or any attached entity field.